# Can I use TinyButStrong Fields to control paragraph formatting in my Word Table

Tags: opentbs, tinybutstrong

I have a word table being populated from a MYSQL query and sub query via an OpenTBS template. The main query acts has a single cell merged across the row; the first column of the subquery is merged using an `ope=mergecell` command; the remaining columns are single cell.

Is there any way I can use openTBS fields to set paragraph 'keep with next' on all rows of the subquery except the last so that all rows of each sub record remain on the same page?

An excerpt from the template would be:

[image: Template excerpt]

So what I am essentially after after merging would be to have the green cells with 'Keep With Next' set and the red cells with that property unset.

[image]

Comment: Even without template consideration, I cannot manage to have an Ms Word table with some rows merged vertically, and having the option "keep with next" working for convenient rows. For example, I have a table with 10 rows ; r6,r7 and r8 have the first cells merged together, r7 and r8 are separated with a line break ; how do you manage to have r6,r7,r8 on the same page ?

Comment: I've now modified my SQL to include a last row flag 
SELECT *, IF(`index` = (SELECT MAX(`index`) FROM `Table`),1,0) FROM `Table`
So hopefully all I need to do is get <w:keepNext/> into the right place in the XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution

For now TBS has no specific feature to know when a record is the last or not (TBS version 3.11.0).
(there are the [headergrp](https://www.tinybutstrong.com/manual.php#html_block_prm_headergrp) and [footergrp](https://www.tinybutstrong.com/manual.php#html_block_prm_footergrp) feature but they do not act on the record but around the record)

So, the first step is to get a an extra column in the data that says if its the last record or not. Let’s say the column is named  *is_last*.
Such a column can theorically be done with MySQL using a window function. Something like :

```
(id = (LAST_VALUE(id) OVER (...)) AS is_last
```

If you don’t succeed in having this column directly thought the MySQL query, then you can load all your data in a PHP array. Since your have a main block and sub-block, then you data should be structured as a recordset for the main block, and each record should have  a sub-recordset stored in a *sample_lst* column (or whatever its name).
Then you template should parameter `sub1` instead of `p1` in order to work with [automatic subblocks](https://www.tinybutstrong.com/manual.php#html_block_subauto).
Now that your data is in a PHP variable, it is easy to visit the data and add the *is_last* column.

Since you have the *is_last* colmun, the next steps are easy:

1. In your template, make 2 conditional sections for the sub-block. On section with `when [sub.is_last]=0`, and the other with `when [sub.is_last]=1`. Knowing you seems to be already using conditional sections for this subblock, you have to arrange the condition in order to combine two conditions as for making an AND. [See FAQ](https://www.tinybutstrong.com/support.php#faq_or).
2. In the section for `is_last=0`, turn off the *Keep with next* Ms Word property.
3. In the section for `is_last=1`, turn on the *Keep with next* Ms Word property.

Comment: Works like a charm thank you. Just missed the work around for combining two `when` instructions.